# I do not have the /craft/storage/runtime/logs/ folder

Tags: craft3, emails, logs

I am trying to set up SMTP emails using Microsoft 365 and the settings are not working so I need to dig into the logs to find out why.

When I go to find the folder it is not there. Instead I have a /craft/storage/logs/ folder but this does not seem to contain the file containing email test logs - [[exception.Craft\EmailTestException]](https://craftcms.com/guides/troubleshooting-email-errors)

I have tried turning dev mode on to see if that changed the logs I was getting, and it does, but I am still not getting the logs I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that article needs to be updated for Craft 3.

In Craft 3, the logs folder is at `storage/logs` and you can search for `[error]` and find the one related to email sending.

Comment: Thanks Brad, found what I am looking for. The [locating error logs](https://craftcms.com/guides/locating-error-logs-and-database-backups) article also needs to be updated!